# pandas python : how import excel file from a line number

Tags: python, excel, pandas

From a excel file and a given line number (e.g. 3), How could we import the selection to a dataframe in pandas ?

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.read_excel('fille.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet', FROM LINE = 3 ?)
```

I cannot slice after the import since my first line owns multicolumns that I want to neglect.

Comment: Include your code while asking the question.

Comment: `skiprows`? `pd.read_excel(file,skiprows=2)`

Comment: thanks,skiprow did the job directly from the import.